# Missing JAR manifest after running DataStax Enterprise 4.7

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I tried installing it 2 times and still got the same error.

I followed the instructions here. http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html

```
root@node1:~$ Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/sbin/../lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Somehow you need to get ./resources/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar in your your DSE installation directory and remove any older versions.

DSE 4.7 uses Cassandra 2.1.8 under the hood. C* 2.1 uses jamm 3.0. Older versions of cassandra, 2.0 and previous used jamm 2.5. If you had a previous install of either an older c* or an older DSE on this environment, some of your old dependencies may be stuck.

If you're on Debian using the package installer try running:

```
sudo aptitude install dse-full=version
```

Which should pick up the right dependencies.

If not, apt-get purge dse-full and then re-installing might also work.

There are similar commands for yum in RHEL.